# Object In/Out stream. How to send updated, same object repeatedly and efficiently?

Tags: java, list, networking, arraylist, io

I've been having some trouble trying to send a list of data using TCP. I've made a smaller version of the problem and exaggerated it a bit.

CLIENT

```
public class Client {

    DListStorage dl = new DListStorage();
    Data d = new Data();

    Socket socket;

    public Client(){
        d.x = 0;
        dl.dl.add(d);

        try {
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                oos.writeObject(dl);
                dl.dl.get(0).x++;
                System.out.println("Client: " + dl.dl.get(0).x);
            }

            socket.close();
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                oos.writeObject(dl);
                dl.dl.get(0).x++;
                System.out.println("Client: " + dl.dl.get(0).x);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

SERVER

```
public class NewConnections {

    ServerSocket ssocket;
    Socket socket;

    public NewConnections(){
        acceptConnections.start();
    }

    Thread acceptConnections = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                ssocket = new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
                socket = ssocket.accept();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                DListStorage dl;

                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    dl = (DListStorage)ois.readObject();
                    System.out.println("Server: " + dl.dl.get(0).x);
                }

                socket.close();
                socket = ssocket.accept();
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    dl = (DListStorage)ois.readObject();
                    System.out.println("Server: " + dl.dl.get(0).x);
                }

                ssocket.close();
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The results for me are as follows.

```
Client: 0.0
Client: 1.0
Server: 0.0
Client: 2.0
Server: 0.0
Server: 0.0
Client: 3.0
Client: 4.0
Server: 3.0
Client: 5.0
Server: 3.0
Server: 3.0
```

Both Data and DataStorage implement Serializable, DataStorage contains
`public List<Data> dl = new ArrayList<>();`
I cant figure out why the server isn't reading the float x properly. Only on the initial read.

Thanks

Comment: I've added `oos.reset()` and it's working but I really need this to be as efficient as possible. Doesn't that cause a lot of overhead, opening and closing the stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class NewConnections {

public NewConnections() {
    acceptConnections.start();
}

Thread acceptConnections = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            int port = 81;
            ServerSocket ssocket = new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("waiting...");
                Socket socket = ssocket.accept();
                // buffered reader to read a line at a time from client
                BufferedReader ois = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));

                String x = null;
                // read till input is available from client
                while ((x = ois.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Server: " + x);
                }
                ois.close();
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

public Client() {
    int port = 81;
    int x = 0;
    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port);
        // use auto flush to send the data immediately to the server
        PrintWriter oos = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            x++;
            oos.println(x);
            System.out.println("Client: " + x);
        }
        oos.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Start the server thread in an infinite loop that is waiting for an input per line. Now send the data line by line from client and it will be flushed immediately to the server.

Comment: I will get back to you on that. I found this [link](http://note4j.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/when-to-reset-objectoutputstream.html) to be of much help about resetting the out stream. It also gives a little insight to why there is a problem to begin with. Thx.

Comment: Sorry it took so long busy week.. I need an array of objects to be sent over otherwise I'd need to code a lot more to account for each individual value (in the data class) that gets sent from the client one after the other. Data is holding size, positions, boolean and some other values. It's for a moving sprite and for whats happening to it. The server needs to be told about everything so the sprite gets dealt with the right way. Advice about other options is good too. I'm looking to send and receive data over the internet